# MongoDB CoffeeScript find document with several fields

Tags: mongodb, coffeescript

How can I check if there are any documents with both name: "John" and age: 40?

This doesn't seem to be working

```
    db.Event.findOne name: "John", age: 40, (error, result) ->
        unless result
            db.Event.save {name: "John", age: 40}
            # document not found, so add it
            inserted = true
        else
            # document found
            inserted = false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need the **[`$setOnInsert`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/#op._S_setOnInsert)** update operator which when used with the update flag **[`{ "upsert": true }`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-parameter)** within an atomic **[`update()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update)** operation, the operation inserts a new document and **[`$setOnInsert`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/#op._S_setOnInsert)** assigns the specified values to the fields in the document. If the update operation does not result in an insert, **[`$setOnInsert`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/#op._S_setOnInsert)** does nothing:

**JavaScript**:

```
var data = {
    "name": "John",
    "age": 40
}

db.Event.update(
    data,
    { "$setOnInsert": data },
    { "upsert": true }
)
```

**CoffeeScript**:

```
data = 
  'name': 'John'
  'age': 40
db.Event.update data, { '$setOnInsert': data }, 'upsert': true
```

Comment: How can I set a boolean value `inserted` to true if inserted and false otherwise?

Comment: You can use a callback, I "enhanced" chriman answer just below.

Comment: Use a callback as @ShanShan specified but it's considered bad practice here on SO to change your question when someone has answered. I had answered on the premise of your initial question, and looks like this [**revision**](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33067678/1) is solved isn't it? As for the ["next"](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33067678/2) problem, that would be a different question, consider posting it separately.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that part initially. I'll make a separate question if I change it next time!

Answer (score 1):

A callback to manage `inserted` boolean:

```
data =
    'name': 'John'
    'age': 40

inserted = false
db.Event.update data,
    { '$setOnInsert': data },
    'upsert': true,
    (error, result) ->
        inserted = not error
```